# how to retrieve dhcp client ip addresses in python

Tags: python, ip, dhcp

On linux, I use the "dumpleases" command to get the ip addresses detected by my dhcp server, then see which is active (pingable).
Is there a package that can do this in python?
I tried IPy but could not figure out a way to list dhcp client ip addresses.
Thanks

Comment: why don't you call the command from Python and parse the output?

Comment: That's what I'm doing but that is platform dependent and server dependent. If there is a better way, please share the idea. Thanks.